# How to set a custom mapbox token for Kepler in python/jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, kepler.gl

My kepler maps stopped rendering in Jupyter notebooks, and I suspect it's because I ran out of requests for the free public mapbox token - I think so because if I try to use mapbox tiles from folium I get an empty map, but if I use OSM tiles everything works fine. I've also tried every possible solution from https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/issues/583

I've tried googling this and digging into the source code, but all the references to the mapbox token I could find are in the .js files, and I'm not really familiar with Javascript

The code is just this, the commented line is approximately what I'm looking for

```
from keplergl import KeplerGl
map_1 = KeplerGl()
#map_1 = KeplerGl(mapbox_api_token = some_token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Add Map Style option to add the custom token and add a custom base map. When you save the map as a html on Jupyter, it retains the token and loads the custom base map.

[Add Map Style Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiYwN.png)